# Print two columns, where one column has a condition?

Tags: pandas

How do I print two columns, where one column has a condition? I want to print all the cities that were first time disclosing, and exclude those cities that have disclosed previously. I've tried combinations similar to the below.

```
print(US20_df[{'City'} {'First Time Discloser'] == 'Yes'}])

print(US20_df['City',('First Time Discloser' == 'Yes')])


City First Time Discloser
Dallas           Yes
Chicago           No
Memphis           No
```

Comment: It would help if you posted (as text) a portion of your dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0):

If you do this

```
US20_df = pd.DataFrame({'City':['Dallas','Chicago', 'Memphis'], 'First Time Discloser' : ['Yes', 'No', 'No']})
US20_df[US20_df['First Time Discloser']=='Yes']
```

you should get

```
    City    First Time Discloser
0   Dallas  Yes
```

Comment: Hi yes that worked and printed those out thank you. That code returns all the other columns as well. How would I just return those two columns?

Comment: like this `US20_df[US20_df['First Time Discloser']=='Yes'] [['City','First Time Discloser']]`